# Cucumber: How to get list of executed steps after each scenario in cucumber JVM

Tags: java, cucumber

I am using cucumber JVM in one of my projects.I want to get list of all steps of a scenario once it fails.Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

A co-worker gave me a bash script for finding steps

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Preparing list of step definitions in directory: $1"
echo "Steps marked with * are unused!"
steps=/tmp/step-definitions.txt
ack-grep "^\s*@(Given|When|Then|And).+" --java -h $1 | sed -r -e 's/^ +@(Given|When|Then|And) *\([^"]*|\) *$//g' -e 's/^"\^?|"$//g' | sort > $steps

used=used-steps.txt
unused=unused-steps.txt
> $used
> $unused

echo "Determine step definition usage:"
while read regex; do
  lc=$(find $1 -iname "*.feature" | xargs egrep "$regex" | wc -l)
  printf -v lcf "%03d" $lc
  if [[ $lc == 0 ]]; then
    echo "* $regex"
    echo $regex >> $unused
  else
    echo "  $regex"
    echo "$lcf uses: $regex" >> $used
  fi
done < $steps
```

Comment: I think yard-cucumber is in ruby.But I require this using java.

Answer (score 0):

If any still looking for these here after this many years :
In the After hook, you can go for scenario.pickle.steps and get all the steps in that scenario. Here is a js snippet for that. You can easily convert it into Java, I guess.

```
 After(function (scenario) {
    console.log("scenario step : ",scenario.pickle.steps)
    });
```

which will return something like

```
    [
  {
    id: '38xc9425-5xc0-50d0-4249-8699-b496d77062db',
    text: 'following is body data:',
    type: 'Context',
    argument: { docString: [Object] },
    astNodeIds: [ '23628ec2-499c-38xc9425-5xc0-bf5b-4398e609f0ff' ]
  },
  {
    id: '38xc9425-5xc0-890f-4436-9b02-dd2fa506ff7b',
    text: 'user send a "post" request to "my url",
    type: 'Action',
    argument: { docString: [Object] },
    astNodeIds: [
      '04961ebc-4e8c-4cb3-b910-38xc9425-5xc0',
      'df2aec66-8d24-4972-38xc9425-5xc0bae416cf'
    ]
  }
```

I hope this works for you.